# How to disable or remove addeventlistener inside a for loop?

Tags: javascript

I am making a tic tac toe game and it's basically done, everything works... except that I can still click on buttons after a winner has been announced. I want the click function to be disabled or removed when someone has won but don't know how. I tried to do a let winStatus = false and then changed winStatus = true if anyone won and if it was true, removeEventListener, but it didn't work because for some reason the for loop didn't want to read it.

here's my js code.

```
const player1 = "X";
const player2 = "O";
let winnerAnnounce = document.querySelector("#print");

let gameDraws = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
let clicks = 0;

const inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input");
let turn = 0;


for (let input of inputs){
    input.addEventListener('click', (evt) =>{
        const id = evt.target.id;
        const box = evt.target;
        if (turn % 2 === 0){
            console.log(player1 + " " + id[1] );
            gameDraws = checkBoxes(evt, gameDraws, player1, id, box);
        } else {
            console.log(player2 + " " + id[1] );
            gameDraws = checkBoxes(evt, gameDraws, player2, id, box);
        }
        checkWin(gameDraws);
        turn++;
    })

};

function checkBoxes (evt, gameDraws, player, id, box){
    if (gameDraws[id[1]-1] === 0){
        gameDraws[id[1]-1]= player; 
        box.value = player;
        clicks++;
    } else if (gameDraws[id[1]-1]=== "X" || gameDraws[id[1]-1] === "O") {
        turn--;
    }
    console.log(gameDraws);
    return gameDraws;
};

function checkWin(gameDraws, winStatus){
    for (let i = 0;i <= 6;i = i + 3){
       if (gameDraws[i] === "X" && gameDraws[i + 1]=== "X" && gameDraws[i + 2] === "X"){
        winnerAnnounce.textContent = player1 + " won!";
        
       } else if (gameDraws[i] === "O" && gameDraws[i + 1]=== "O" && gameDraws[i + 2] === "O"){
        winnerAnnounce.textContent = player2 + " won!";
       }
       
    };
    for (let i = 0; i <= 2; i++){
        if(gameDraws[i] === "X" && gameDraws[i + 3]=== "X" && gameDraws[i + 6] === "X"){
            winnerAnnounce.textContent = player1 + " won!";
        } else if (gameDraws[i] === "O" && gameDraws[i + 3]=== "O" && gameDraws[i + 6] === "O"){
            winnerAnnounce.textContent = player2 + " won!";
        }
    };
    if (gameDraws[0]=== "X" && gameDraws[4] === "X" && gameDraws[8] === "X"){
        winnerAnnounce.textContent = player1 + " won!";
    } else if (gameDraws[0]=== "O" && gameDraws[4] === "O" && gameDraws[8] === "O"){
        winnerAnnounce.textContent = player2 + " won!";
    } 
    if(gameDraws[2] === "X" && gameDraws[4] === "X" && gameDraws[6] === "X"){
        winnerAnnounce.textContent = player1 + " won!";
    } else if (gameDraws[2] === "X" && gameDraws[4] === "X" && gameDraws[6] === "X"){
        winnerAnnounce.textContent = player2 + " won!";
    }
    if (clicks >= 9){
        winnerAnnounce.textContent = "It's a tie!";
    }
}

const reset = document.querySelector("#but");


reset.addEventListener('click', () => {
    window.location.reload();
})
```

Comment: You can add an overlay with higher `z-index` after the user is won the match and remove the it on play again or restart.

Comment: iterate the buttons and remove their click event listeners when game finished - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener

Answer (score 0):

Just change it to this:

```
input.addEventListener('click',(evt)=>{
...}, {once:true});
```

The event listener will trigger only once. And, your problem will be solved!

But using input fields for a tic tac toe game and adding the eventlistener with loop is not a good practice. The addEventListener method will slow down your code. So, it's better to avoid them. I don't really know your html setup. But, I recommend you to use onclick attribute.

Hope, it helps.